# Microsoft Report Builder 3 Date Sorting

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to sort dates in chronological order but it is not working, Can someone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are returning a string value for your column header dates and then trying to sort on that?  If so, that is your problem.

With dates stored as strings, just like `a` comes before `b` and `aabbcc` comes before `abcabc` in alphabetical order, `1. February` comes before `26. January` because the character `1` precedes the character `2`.

If you want to organise in date order instead of alphabetical order, you need to return actual date values instead of formatted text strings.

Thankfully, as SSRS is a presentation tool it is very capable of formatting your date values into almost any format you require.  In your case you would need to set the format expression to

```
=format(Fields!YourActualDateValueInsteadOfAFormattedString.Value, "d. MMMM yyyy")
```

Comment: The date comes from my company CUBE. It is fine on there and on the pre-view in the query builder it shows the dates sorted fine. I have used the suggestion above and it still isn't sorting correctly

Comment: @TrevTurner  I would imagine the cube data is sorted on an actual date value and you are selecting a string that is being used for presentation.  Is there not an actual `date` type value you can select instead of this string one and if not, can you get it included into the cube?

Comment: i have now got a format of dd.MM.yyyy but is still not sorting correctly

Comment: @TrevTurner  If you are formatting a string then of course they won't.  `01.02.2017` comes before `02.01.2017` when sorted alphabetically.  The only way you will get your strings to sort is to either convert them to a `date` data type using the `cdate` function or formatting them to be `yyyy.MM.dd`